# SAS_Count Frequency

Tags: sas

I want to ask a complicated (for me) question about SAS programming. I think I can explain better by using simple example. So, I have the following dataset:

```
 Group          Category 
 A                  1
 A                  1
 A                  2
 A                  1
 A                  2
 A                  3
 B                  1
 B                  2
 B                  2
 B                  1
 B                  3
 B                  2
```

I want to count the each category for each group. I can do it by using PROC FREQ. But it is not better way for my dataset. It will be time consuming for me as my dataset is too large and I have a huge number of groups. So, if I use PROC FREQ, firstly I need to create new datasets for each group and then use PROC FREQ for each group. In sum, I need to create the following dataset:

```
                               CATEGORIES 
 Group     1   (first category)         2             3                                                                    
 A         3                            2             1
 B         2                            3             1
```

So, the number of first category in group A is 3. The number of first category in group B is 2 and so on. I think I can explain it. Thanks for your helps.

Comment: PROC FREQ works fine, whatever you're trying to do, you're likely doing it incorrectly. WHICH is exactly why you're supposed to post your code in a SO question.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to do this in SAS.  My bias is `proc sql`, so:

```
proc sql;
    select grp,
           sum(case when category = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as cat_1,
           sum(case when category = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as cat_2,
           sum(case when category = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as cat_3
    from t
    group by grp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either `proc freq` or `proc summary` will do the job of producing frequency counts:

```
data example;
 length group category $1;
 input group category;
cards;
A 1
A 1
A 2
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 1
B 2
B 2
B 1
B 3
B 2
;
run;

proc freq data=example;
 table group*category;
run;

proc summary data=example nway;
 class group category;
 output out=example_frequency (drop=_type_);
run;
```

`proc summary` will produce a dataset in a 'long' format.  If you need to transpose it (I'd suggest not doing so: you'll probably find working with the long format easier in most circumstances) you can use `proc transpose`:

```
proc transpose data=example_frequency out=example_matrix (drop=_name_);
 by group;
 id category;
 var _freq_;
run;
```